# What filesystem or file format is this?

Tags: linux, filesystems, embedded-linux

I have a great amplifier that sadly no longer gets any support (a Kickstarter gone bad). It can however be upgraded with an .img file. The unit runs Linux and the OS is installed on some kind of embedded storage (not a disk drive)

I have tried writing the img to an SD card with no success. A lot of Kickstarter backers will be very happy if we can figure this one out.

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Update:

```
$ file usbupgrade_O.0.31.69.img 
usbupgrade_O.0.31.69.img: data
```

Comment: What does `file` say it is?

Comment: just <filename>.img

Comment: So it only returns "data"?

Comment: The two screenshots show the initial data in the file

Comment: But have you actually tried running `file` against it?

Comment: Do you have a link to the Kickstarter (or any message forum about the product)?

Comment: $ file usbupgrade_O.0.31.69.img 
usbupgrade_O.0.31.69.img: data

Comment: Some info on the device: http://www.myoliveone.com

Comment: The entire file can be downloaded here (170MB): https://slack-files.com/T1D6HPX2A-F1D8CJASD-b5a5000a1e

Comment: [binwalk](http://binwalk.org/) is made for this kind of work. Try running it against your image file; if it's any standard format, it'll tell you what it is. (Even if it isn't, it'll tell you a lot about what's in there.)

Comment: @duskwuff Great tip, I will see if I can get it through Homebrew (mac)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 0):

Using binwalk as suggested by @duskwuff gave the following info:

```
$ binwalk usbupgrade_O.0.31.69.img 

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4096          0x1000          uImage header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0xC2CEE548, created: 2016-04-19 06:16:47, image size: 3219180 bytes, Data Address: 0x10008000, Entry Point: 0x10008000, data CRC: 0x47F1092, OS: Linux, CPU: ARM, image type: OS Kernel Image, compression type: none, image name: "Linux-3.0.35"
20871         0x5187          gzip compressed data, maximum compression, from Unix, NULL date (1970-01-01 00:00:00)
5246976       0x501000        OpenSSL encryption, salted, salt: 0x-187DE192-39315650
130464447     0x7C6BABF       StuffIt Deluxe Segment (data): f$
148645351     0x8DC25E7       VMware4 disk image
```

So I guess it is an uImage. I´m a bit surprised of the VMware4 disk image, is this normal to include in this kind of images?

Comment: The VMWare disk image, and the StuffIt Deluxe segment, are probably both false positives. Binwalk isn't 100% accurate.